# ANSI TERM via `M-x TERM`: How to change line highlighting color?

Tags: themes, colors, ansi-term, term

How do you change the line-highlighting color in an ANSI-TERM?:

I am using PDB++'s sticky mode for Python debugging. This is how to appears on a regular terminal (lubuntu 17.04):

[image]

Notice the word `print` in the image above is visible. However, when launching terminal emulation in EMACS (empty .init file) via `M-x term` or `M-x ansi-term` and `Run Program: /bin/bash`, the `print` word is not visible as it is the same color as the highlighter:

[image]

I'd like to change the highlight color so the word `print` is visible. I know this is possible as the Prelude variant of EMACS looks like this:

[image]

However, I'm not sure what code in the Prelude configuration is responsible for line highlighting color in terminal emulation. Can anyone assist me? Please help.

Comment: Did you try ansi-term instead of term?

Comment: Yes. The same result appears in ANSI-TERM